# Fazer um HasMany por data com Laravel 5.3?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-eloquent, laravel-5.3

Existe alguma forma de fazer um `HasMany` trazendo registros por data?

```
public function despesas()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Despesa::class); //registros apenas desse mês
}
```

*Tentei usar o seguinte, mas não rolou:*

```
public function despesaMes()
{
    return DB::table('despesa')->whereDate('data_vencimento' , '=', date('Y-m'))->get();
}
```

O formato salvo é `Y-m-d H:i:s`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Definição no relacionamento

No Laravel, é possível adicionar uma cláusula where num método que define o relacionamento entre entidades.

Veja:

```
public function despesas()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Despesa::class); //registros apenas desse mês
}


public function despesasMes()
{
      return $this->despesas()->where('data_vencimento' , '=', date('Y-m'));
}
```

Outro detalhe: Já que você vai consultar por mês e por ano, sugiro utilizar os métodos `whereMonth` e `whereYear` para fazer isso.

Veja:

```
public function despesasMes()
{
      return $this->despesas()
                 ->whereMonth('data_vencimento', '=', date('m'))
                 ->whereYear('data_vencimento', '=', date('Y'));
}
```

## Definição na consulta:

Outra forma interessante de se trabalhar é definir a condição de qual mês e ano estão as despesas desejadas no momento da consulta, e não na declaração do relacionamento.

Veja:

```
$relacionamento['despesas'] = function ($query) {
   $query->whereYear('data_vencimento' , '=', date('Y'))
         ->whereMonth('data_vencimento', '=', date('m'));
};

$model = Model::with($relacionamento)->find(1);
```

Assim, quando você acessar os valores de `$model->despesas`, apenas as `despesas` que estiverem dentro da condição `where` definida na `Closure` serão retornados.

Comment: Bem observado, coloquei o formato na pergunta

Comment: Funcionou amigo, muito obrigado